# Keyword density calculation on a keyword phrase?

Tags: php, string

When attempting to calculate the keyword density of a single keyword in a string of content, the formula is pretty straightforward: kwd = (keyword count / total word count ) * 100

However, what should the formula be when we are looking for keyword density of a keyword phrase?

For example, how would you calculate the keyword density of the phrase "blue widgets" in the following string?

```
$myContent = "Blue widgets in a field
of widgets blue makes for lots of widgets, true. But
if a widget is blue, is it still a
\"blue widget\" or just a lone widget in a sea
of blue?";
```

Here's my current function

```
function my_keyword_density($post)
{
    $word_count =  my_word_count($post);
    $keyword_count = my_keyword_count($post);
    $density = ($keyword_count / $word_count) * 100;
    $density = number_format($density, 1);
return $density;
}
```

How can I get a count of the number of words in the keyword phrase?

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks for escaping the quotes!

Comment: keyword count / total word count, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
$tot_words = str_word_count($myContent);
$keyword_count = preg_match_all("/\bblue widgets\b/msiU", $myContent, $res);
$kwd = ($keyword_count / $tot_words) * 100;
```

If you need to customize what is considereded a "word" you can add a parameter to the str_word_count function, [see the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php). The just add error checking where needed and it should work. 
About the formula, I'd use something like this:

```
    $search_words = str_word_count("blue widgets");
    $kwd = ($keyword_count / ($tot_words - (($keyword_count -1) * $search_words));
```

This way you'll handle all the multi word keyphrase as if it's single-worded. Hope it helps

Comment: would you not account for the number of keywords in the phrase in the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to imply that you want to take each keyword into account as well as the keyword phrase. In that case, you might use a weighted formula:

```
kwd = α*kwd("blue widgets") + (1-α)*(kwd("blue")+kwd("widgets"))
```

`α=1` gives the most conservative measure (only the phrase "blue widgets" is relevant),
`α=0` gives the most liberal measure (both "blue" and "widgets" anywhere in the text are relevant).

Comment: only want to match the exact keyword phrase "blue widgets", "blue" or "widget" is not necessarily a match.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

kwd = (total word count / num key phrase occurances) / num words in key phrase